# Using `human_attribute_name` with nested class in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have class:

```
module Import
  class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

I would like to use `Import::Log.human_attribute_name(:results)`.
I already found that this will (in method) end with call

```
I18n.translate('activerecord.attributes.import/log.results', {:count=>1, :default=>[:"attributes.results", "Results"]})
```

But  I do not know how to write translation file.
Tried YML

```
cs:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      import/log:
        results: "Výsledky běhu"
```

Tried ruby hash

```
{
  cs: {
    activerecord: {
      attributes: {
        'import\/log': {
          results: "Výsledky běhu"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing works.
Any idea?

I

Comment: The YAML seems right. Are you sure the current locale for that request or irb session is indeed 'cs'? Also, If that is a new locale file and you're testing this through a web request, don't forget to restart the server because rails doesn't pick up new translation files before each request.

Comment: Yes, locale is 'cs' (non ar.attributes translations are shown correctly). And I restarted server even it is old locale file.

Comment: Is there any change the key activerecord is present in another translation file? I18n doesn't merge YAML keys so if there's another it can be overriding this one and these attributes aren't been taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake somewhere.
After @Alexanders comments, I try i from the start and voilá! The Yaml version `import/log:` works.

Probably I tried first Yaml translation in new file without restarting server and then check other (now wrong) versions through capybara tests.

Alexander, Thank you very much.